# How to paste php variable in "span" tags?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have some problem with div content. I have created a website which books must be load from Mysql database to html div content. I have use `printf();` for load data to div content.  But i can't paste php variable between `<span>` tags.

```html
    <?php
require 'scripts/connect.php';
$sql_select = "SELECT * FROM users";
$result = mysql_query($sql_select);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
do
{
    printf(
                    '<ul>
                    <li>
                        <div class="product">
                            <a href="#" class="info">
                                <span class="holder">
                                    <img src="css/images/image01.jpg" alt="" />
                                    <span class="book-name">$row['b_name'] </span>     //ERROR IN HERE
                                    <span class="author">$row['a_name']</span>     //AND HERE
                                    <span class="description">Maecenas vehicula ante eu enim pharetra<br />scelerisque dignissim <br />sollicitudin nisi</span>
                                </span>
                            </a>
                            <a href="#" class="buy-btn">BUY NOW <span class="price"><span class="low">$</span>22<span class="high">00</span></span></a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    </ul>'
                    );
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result));
         ?>
```

How i can do this ? Thanks

Comment: Do not use `mysql_*` functions.

Comment: And please, use snippets only for HTML / CSS / JavaScript. Not for PHP.

Answer (score 3):

If you ask me, I would do this way, without `mysql_*` functions and **separating PHP and HTML**. The problem with yours is, **`'` quotes do not expand variables**.

```
<?php
require 'scripts/connect.php';
$sql_select = "SELECT * FROM users";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_select);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
    while (false != ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))) { ?>
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="product">
            <a href="#" class="info">
                <span class="holder">
                    <img src="css/images/image01.jpg" alt="" />
                    <span class="book-name"><?php echo $row['b_name']; ?></span>
                    <span class="author"><?php echo $row['a_name']; ?></span>
                    <span class="description">Maecenas vehicula ante eu enim pharetra<br />scelerisque dignissim <br />sollicitudin nisi</span>
                </span>
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="buy-btn">BUY NOW <span class="price"><span class="low">$</span>22<span class="high">00</span></span></a>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
<?php } ?>
```

In the above code, I am assuming `$conn` is the `mysqli_connect` variable.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are mixing double quotes and single quotes. PHP variables can only be outputted inside double quotes. Change all of your existing double quotes to single quotes, and then encapsulate the `<ul>` in double quotes:

```
"<ul>
    <li>
      <div class='product'>
        <a href='#' class='info'>
          <span class='holder'>
            <img src='css/images/image01.jpg' alt='' />
            <span class='book-name'>$row['b_name']</span>
            <span class='author'>$row['a_name']</span>
            <span class='description'>Maecenas vehicula ante eu enim pharetra<br />scelerisque dignissim <br />sollicitudin nisi</span>
          </span>
        </a>
        <a href='#' class='buy-btn'>BUY NOW
          <span class='price'>
             <span class='low'>$</span>22
             <span class='high'>00</span>
          </span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </li>
 </ul>"
```

Of course, you could always restructure to simply output the content as HTML, then inject the PHP variables:

`<span><?php echo $row['b_name']; ?></span>`

Also be aware that `mysql()` calls are deprecated in PHP 5.5, and outright **removed** in PHP 7.0, so consider using MySQLi or PDO instead :)

Hope this helps!

Comment: "you're using echo() inside your printf()" no he is not

Comment: @ObsidianAge I am not sure why it didn't solve, but since you have really a good rep, don't post like this. Don't give excuses.

Comment: @PraveenKumar "Don't post like this" -- I wanted to get the solution out quickly, then format the code after posting my solution. Unformatted, my code is perfectly valid. Instead of criticizing my lack of formatting, how about encouraging solutions that are alternative to yours, rather than bullying the people who write them, driving them away from the site. You have a rep that far exceeds mine, so I will say the same back to you, "Don't post like this".

Comment: @ObsidianAge What's a good answer mate? Not offending you, but the quality of Stack Overflow has declined. It is better to wait and post a good question rather than posting quickies. Do you agree? **I never discouraged your solution, I was just concerned that your good solution should be seen in a proper way!**